# Is there a way to delete files from document server in Integration Edition of onlyoffice for Windows?

Tags: windows, server, onlyoffice

I deployed Integration edition of OnlyOffice server on Windows. The deployment is successfully working but the document server keeps the files on its storage disk for 1 week which I don't want for some security reasons. So is there a way possible to delete files from document server after the editing is done or to delete files from server at a regular configurable interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shuould update your integration to latest version - we changed timeout for removing file for one day since https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/server/commit/41e3ea15626e354c9bfb6727da8118da248ff35e version 4.2
Or you can try to change this option in server config

Comment: How to change the option in server config?

Comment: edit file `C:\Program Files\ONLYOFFICE\DocumentServer\example\config`

Comment: The directory you specified has many json files and each json file has many parameters. How would I know which parameter is used for what purpose and which parameter I am supposed to change to serve my purpose. Is there any proper documentation for this?

Comment: You should look to commit I attached in answer. You should change `default.json` - `services/CoAuthoring/expire/files`

Comment: The value for this parameter is in seconds or in minutes or in hours or in days?

Comment: Value in seconds

Comment: What if I set file expiry time to 5 minutes and keep on editing file for more than 5 minutes?

Comment: We not trying to delete files, that currently in edit, so it's pretty safe